# Assigning JavaFX Label Font from Combobox not working

Tags: java, list, javafx, combobox, observablelist

I am trying to assign the font of a label(`node`) by selecting the value from a combobox I constructed.  The combobox has only a few options, so all of them should be safe to use in this app.

Everything works fine, and all the correct string value from the combobox is being pulled and assigned to the label.  But the font in the label doesn't change, and when I output the font from the label the active font is still the system default.   I have another method that edits only the `fontSize`, and that works fine.  So it must be the actual string value being invalid.  But no error is thrown, and the combobox list names were gotten from the installed fonts on the system.

The Use case and the code is below.  What am I missing?

**1) Select Font and Click OK** changed)

[image]

**2) Assigned to label** (Code snippets)

```
String font = String.valueOf(combobox_font.getValue());

label.setFont(Font.font(font));
```

Note:  For the sake of my program I'm trying to assign font type and size separately, but I also tried assigning the values with the font size with no luck.

```
label.setFont(Font.font(font, fontSize)); ///fontSize is a double value gotten from teh textfled above
```

**3)  Outbut Label Font**  (Still System Default)

```
   Font[name=System Regular, family=System, style=Regular, size=12.0]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are specifying the font name instead of the family name, you need to use the constuctor of `Font`, since all the static methods expect the font family:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    ComboBox<String> fontChoice = new ComboBox<>(FXCollections.observableList(Font.getFontNames()));

    Spinner<Integer> spinner = new Spinner<>(1, 40, 12);

    Text text = new Text("Hello World!");

    text.fontProperty().bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> new Font(fontChoice.getValue(), spinner.getValue()), spinner.valueProperty(), fontChoice.valueProperty()));

    HBox hBox = new HBox(fontChoice, spinner);
    StackPane.setAlignment(hBox, Pos.TOP_CENTER);

    StackPane root = new StackPane(hBox, text);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

To use the static methods, use the family names:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    ComboBox<String> familyChoice = new ComboBox<>(FXCollections.observableList(Font.getFamilies()));

    Spinner<Integer> spinner = new Spinner<>(1, 40, 12);

    Text text = new Text("Hello World!");
    text.fontProperty().bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> Font.font(familyChoice.getValue(), spinner.getValue()), spinner.valueProperty(), familyChoice.valueProperty()));

    HBox hBox = new HBox(familyChoice, spinner);
    StackPane.setAlignment(hBox, Pos.TOP_CENTER);

    StackPane root = new StackPane(hBox, text);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: That did it.  I replaced `font.font(font)` with `new Font(font, fontSize)` and it works like a charm.   Thanks.